# Restoring an AWS Snapshot and using it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I have a snapshot and I can start a new EC2 and attach it but I cannot access the snapshot on the EBS drive without formatting it which destroys the data. Here is the command list I am using:

```
cat /proc/partitions
sudo mke2fs -F -t ext4 /dev/xvdf
sudo mount /dec/xvdf /data
```

This works but the EBS is empty due to the mke2fs.

How can I just mount the EBS snapshot and hence use it under /data?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mke2fs`.  As you have observed, that reformats the volume.  If, for some reason, you don't think you can otherwise mount it, you may be mounting the wrong logical entity.

Identify the device or partition with `lsblk` and then mount it, as above.

If there are partitions, you need to supply the partition, not the device, as an argument to `mount`.

```
/dev/xvde  # device
/dev/xvde1 # first partition
```